# Asynchronously update IndexedDB in upgrade event

Tags: javascript, database, asynchronous, transactions, indexeddb

In the `onupgradeneeded()` event for IndexedDB I am trying to update each record in an object store. In order to update them I need to first preform an async operation but this causes the upgrade transaction to become inactive and I get the error

`Failed to execute 'update' on 'IDBCursor': The transaction is not active.`

In the follow code I am simulating an async operation with `setTimeout()`

```
let openRequest = indexedDB.open('myDb', 1);

openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (versionEvent) {
    let db = versionEvent.target['result'];
    let upgradeTransaction = versionEvent.target['transaction'];

    if(versionEvent.oldVersion < 1) {
        let objStore = db.createObjectStore('sample');
        objStore.add('one', '1');
        objStore.add('two', '2');
    }

    if(versionEvent.oldVersion >= 1) {
        let getCursor = upgradeTransaction.objectStore('sample').openCursor();

        getCursor.onsuccess = (e) => {
          let cursor = e.target['result'];
          if (cursor) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              cursor.update(cursor.value + ' updated');
              cursor.continue();
            })
          }
        }
    }
};
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/DIIzLduZT1dwOEHAdzSf?p=preview

If you run this plunker it will initialize IndexedDB. Then if you increase the version number to 2 and run it again you will get the error.

How can I update IndexedDB in an upgrade event if my update relies on an async operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a different approach. Options include:

- Making the schema changes immediately, but deferring adding new data for a subsequent transaction.
- Fetch the data before trying to perform the upgrade. Since fetching the data is slow this is likely not desirable.
- Conditionally fetch the data, only if an upgrade is needed.

There are two approaches for the latter. You could do an `open()` with no version number, check the version, and then fetch/upgrade if it is lower than desired. Or you can open at the new version and in upgradeneeded abort the upgrade (get the transaction from the request and call `abort()` on it) then fetch the data and re-attempt the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks! I think I go with option 3 and and call `open()` with no version number.

Comment: Am I interpreting this correctly: long-running schema upgrade processes *cannot* be done within the "native" `upgradeneeded` event, but *must* be deferred to a developer-managed upgrade process?

Comment: Yes. For better or for worse, it's a design principle of the IndexedDB API.

You might consider using the now widely implemented Web Locks API as an additional layer of coordination around async operations.